# Cannot view webpage completely when loading through Azure URL

Tags: javascript, php, html, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to build a web application in MS Azure using PHP. I have created a login and sign up page where the login page redirects to corresponding user page. I make all the changes on my local system and run locally by running php -S localhost:8080 on powershell and then viewing the page on chrome web browser. All of it runs flawlessly on my local system. You can see my login page as:

[image]
[image]

Then I push all these changes to my account linked with MS Azure but when I run it using the azure url to see if my changes are reflected properly, all I get is this:

[image]

Also my javascript handler does not work which helps me shuffle my form between sing up and log in. I checked my code and it is properly pushed online. What could be the problems for this issue? For uploading I have used git commit and git push on azure master branch.

Here are the details of the error I am getting:
[image: error details]

Comment: When I try to access your webapp, I can see there is a `500 Internal Server Error` error, as [my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43vWi.png) shown. Please refer to the offical tutorial [`Enable diagnostics logging for apps in Azure App Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs) to enable logging features to check and post these logs for helps.

Comment: @PeterPan I have updated the question with the details of the error I am getting.

Comment: That error page is referring to a font file not loading. It is not what is causing the 500 error. Are there any other error logs available once you have enabled diagnostics?

Comment: @SamaraSoucy-MSFT I have updated the error with the error that I am getting in my index.php file.

Comment: @Prachi Normally, a 500 error was caused by the incorrect code logic. Could you post some necessary code for debugging? Such as some declaration code for libraries import, your `web.config` content, and so on if helps.

Comment: @PeterPan I am sorry but I can find no file as `web.config` in my main folder. I directly followed [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-php#push-to-azure-from-git) to clone a php-docs-hello-word folder and started editing the index.php file and linking other files to it and then I push it to the branch I specified as azure as given on the link. This should essentially deploy my code on Azure platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out doing `composer install` in your root folder on your console solves the issue.